# Using R to call a Web Service: Send data and get the result table back in R

Tags: r, web-services, asp.net-web-api, rcurl, httr

http://snomedct.t3as.org/ This is a web service that will analyse English clinical text, and report any concepts that can be detected.
For e.g.- I have headache. It will identify headache as a Symptom.

Now what I would like to do is send the sentence to the web service through R, and get the table back from the web page to R for further analysis purpose.

Comment: have you tried anything or want us to code this for you?

Comment: Take a look at the [rvest](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/) package.

Comment: Sounds like an _awesome_ opportunity to sit down with a cold beverage and peruse the [CRAN Task View on Web Technologies](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/WebTechnologies.html).

Comment: @hrbrmstr I have tried the httr package. I am more into data analysis, and this is a completely new thing for me. Note sure how to send the text from R to the web service.
    # TExt note to be sent to Snomed Browser
    Note<- c("I am suffering from severe headache", "I had a sleepless     night")

    library(httr)
    url<-"http://snomedct.t3as.org/snomed-coder-       web/rest/v1.0/snomedctCodes"
    GET(url)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we take their example `curl` command-line:

```
curl -s --request POST \
        -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
        --data-urlencode "The patient had a stroke." \
        http://snomedct.t3as.org/snomed-coder-web/rest/v1.0/snomedctCodes
```

that can be translated to `httr` pretty easily.

The `-s` means "silent" (no progress meter or error messages) so we don't really have to translate that.

Any `-H` means to add a header to the request. This particular `Content-Type` header can be handled better with the `encode` parameter to `httr::POST`.

The `--data-urlencode` parameter says to URL encode that string and put it in the `body` of the request.

Finally, the URL is the resource to call.

```
library(httr)

result <- POST("http://snomedct.t3as.org/snomed-coder-web/rest/v1.0/snomedctCodes", 
               body="The patient had a stroke.",
               encode="form")
```

Since you don't do this regularly, you can wrap the `POST` call with `with_verbose()` to see what's going on (look that up in the `httr` docs).

There are a ton of nuances that one should technically do after this (like check the HTTP status code with `stop_for_status()`, `warn_for_status()` or even just `status_code()`, but for simplicity let's assume the call works (this one is their example so it does work and returns a `200` HTTP status code which is A Good Thing).

By default, that web service is returning JSON, so we need to convert it to an R object. While `httr` does built-in parsing, I like to use the `jsonlite` package to process the result:

```
dat <- jsonlite::fromJSON(content(result, as="text"),  flatten=TRUE)
```

The `fromJSON` function takes a few parameters that are intended to help shape JSON into a reasonable R data structure (many APIs return horrible JSON and/or XML). This API would fit into the "horrible" category. The data in `dat` is pretty gnarly and further decoding of it would be a separate SO question.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for you lovely explanation.

Comment: please @user3117837 consider marking hrbrmstr 's answer as the right one if it worked for you.